# Не работает Socialite при попытке войти на Facebook

Tags: php, laravel, api, facebook

Решил сделать авторизацию на сайте через соц. сеть Facebook, используя пакет Laravel Socialite (работаю на Laravel 5.6, на локальном сервере). Следовал инструкции на сайте https://www.laragle.com/2017/03/step-by-step-laravel-social-login.html . Все повторил точь-в-точь, но при попытке авторизации вылезает такое сообщение
[image: картинка]

Вроде бы само приложение на Facebook настроил тоже корректно:

[image: картинка2]

Я попробовал даже просто подключиться к аккаунту, как описано в доках: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/socialite - результат тот-же
Ничего толкового по этому вопросу не нашел. Может кто сталкивался с чем-то подобным? Подскажите пожалуйста. что делать в данной ситуации.

Comment: Проверил работу с Google+ API - там все прекрасно работает

Answer (score 0):

Приложения создаваемые на фэйсе стали требовать от обратного вызова протокол https. поэтому возникает ошибка. Обычно все локальные сервера настроены на http.

Посмотрите какой протокол принимает графа на фэйсе: Действительные URI перенаправления для OAuth
https://localhost:8000
или
http://localhost

Я бы задал вопрос как внутренний сервер laravel изменить протокол на HTTPS